# If an input is in the array return true, else false

Tags: java

Fixed it. Working code! I had to move the fruit array into the method and call it from main.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringArrayTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;       

    System.out.println("Enter a fruit: ");
    input = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Is \"" + input + "\" in the array? " + isIn(input));

    sc.close();
}

public static boolean isIn(String input) {

    String[] fruit = new String[6];

    fruit[0] = "grape";
    fruit[1] = "banana";
    fruit[2] = "apple";
    fruit[3] = "mango";
    fruit[4] = "watermelon";
    fruit[5] = "orange";

    for(int i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {
        if (input.equals(fruit[i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: @Reimeus:  It's in the `main` method...that should suffice for now.

Comment: What's the error you get?

Answer (score 4):

The following code will return `true` if the array contains the input and `false` if it doesn't.
Credits to [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr) for this code:

```
Arrays.asList(yourArray).contains(yourString)
```

Answer (score 3):

`return false` must be outside the `for` loop. If it's in the `else` part, the `for` loop will end at the first iteration.

Here's how the code should look like:

```
public boolean isIn(String input) {
    for(int i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {
        if (input.equals(fruit[i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also, you cannot declare a method inside another method. Move the method `isIn` outside `main`.

Other problems in your code:

- `String[] fruit` is currently declared, initialized and filled inside `main` method. It should be at least declared outside as a field of the class in order to be accessed by other methods.
- You're not using `isIn` anywhere.
- In order to use the fields and methods inside `main` method, you have two options:

  1. Declare the fields and methods as `static`.
  2. Create a new instance of your class inside the `main` method and use the fields and methods from this instance.

The code may look like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringArrayTest {
    static String[] fruit = new String[6];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fruit[0] = "grape";
        fruit[1] = "banana";
        fruit[2] = "apple";
        fruit[3] = "mango";
        fruit[4] = "watermelon";
        fruit[5] = "orange";

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;
        input = sc.nextLine();

        if (isIn(input)) {
            //do something...
        } else {
            //do something else...
        }
    }

    public static boolean isIn(String input) {
        for(int i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {
            if (input.equals(fruit[i])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2938819 an error that we don't know since you haven't provided your new code.

Comment: isIn doesn't know where fruit is coming from now.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the suggestions given by others.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringArrayTest {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   String[] fruit = new String [] {"grape", "banana", "apple", "mango", "watermelon", "orange"};

   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   String input = sc.nextLine();

   System.out.println(Arrays.asList(fruit).contains(input));
 }
}
```